# Directly computing a matrix representation with respect to 2 bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I want to find the representation of a linear transformation with respect to two new bases.

Given linear transformation:

$$
L(at + b) = \begin{bmatrix}
 3b-a\\
2a + b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

With:

- $S_1 = (1,t)$ as standard basis of $P_1$ and $T_1$ being the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
- $S_2 = (3t + 5, t + 2)$ as another basis of $P_1$ and $T_2 = \left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know the way to do it using an augmented matrix (image linked):

$$L(3t+5) = \begin{bmatrix}12 \\ 11\end{bmatrix} \\ L(t+2) = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
-1&2&12&5\\
-1&1&11&4
\end{array}\right] \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
-1&2&12&5\\
0&-1&-1&-1
\end{array}\right] \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
-1&0&10&3\\
0&-1&-1&-1
\end{array}\right] \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
1&0&-10&-3\\
0&1&1&1
\end{array}\right] \\
$$
resulting in $$
\boxed{\begin{bmatrix}-10 & -3 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}}
$$
[image]

However, I tried using $Q^{-1}AP$ to solve this: $Q$ is ${Q_{T_{1} \gets T_{2}}}$ and P is ${P_{S_{1} \gets S_{2}}}$. I should get the same answer as what I did above using what I did before, but I get something completely different.

Here's what I tried:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \\
P_{S_1 \gets S_2} = \begin{bmatrix}5&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix} \\
Q_{T_1 \gets T_2} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \\
Q^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix} \\
\implies Q^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

[image: Attempt at 2nd method]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Include what my attempt at the 2nd method was.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you edit your question, adding to you what you have tried using the second method.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the welcome. I just updated the post with what I tried.

Comment: Just converted the attempt to MathJax, you can take a look. Next time, you can use the same syntax (if necessary, copy and paste the elimination matrix syntax) to MathJax your attempt rather than write it. It helps in searchability of your post, posts with MathJax get more attention.

Answer (score -2):

Of course that there is something wrong; you got two different answers, and therefore (at least) one of the approaches must be wrong. In your case, it's the second one. You have used the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&3\\2&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, whereas it should have been $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&-1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. You can check that$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}3&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-10&-3\\1&1\end{bmatrix},$$which is the answer that you got through the first method.